# Android drawable behind a bitmap

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I am trying to achieve this crazy thing but I not sure if this is possible using Android drawable.

I have an image which as some transparent parts, then I am trying to have another gradient sweep element behind this Image to rotate so that the transparent parts of image get moving gradient color.

As of now, I am able to get Image and an gradient sweep behind it but it is not rotating and effect is not as I expected. Any suggestion/tips/code snippets will be helpful.

Here is my drawable XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="360">

            <shape
                android:innerRadiusRatio="15"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thicknessRatio="4"
                android:useLevel="false">

                <gradient
                    android:angle="0"
                    android:endColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:startColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:type="sweep"
                    android:useLevel="false" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/inoffline" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and the output image, I have swapped the transparent parts of image so that i could easily verify that both drawable are rendered.

[image]

Regards,

Harsha

Comment: this may be helpful. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html

Comment: PorterDuff.Mode is new to me. I have to read more but my first impression is that is addresses the need for action when combining two images. I am not able to connect how/where PorterDuff.Mode would apply to my case...

Comment: Ok. I misunderstood ur question.